# Would the placement of the Save Button be better in the top right or under content?

Tags: buttons, save, placement

Would the product be better served with the save button for each tab/section in the top right where it is viewable or at the bottom of the content underneath? I know it is common to place it bottom right but wonder would the visibility at the top be better in this product. Or if there is best practice?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As per the structure of the page that is shown in the image, the heriarchy of button placed at the top right is actually giving out the meaning of saving an entire data with a catch in the button label 'save section' saving the day for the user.

Since it is save section and there is no global save (as per what is shown currently) you can always place it to right bottom corner with a separation line and freeze it always on the screen with other content going inside the scroll.

Something like below.

[image]